# Karaf from penthao timeout

Tags: pentaho, apache-karaf

I have a job with a transformation that takes some hours to end. In this transformation the step that takes so long is an output insert/update step. If I run the job from pdi/spoon, **it ends without errors** after some hours.

However, if I run the job from the command line /scheduled using Kitchen.bat I get some errors like the following. I get the errors after 5 minutes/300 seconds, so it must be a timeout somewhere. Because these ETL jobs may take hours, I reallly need to identify and set a new timeout value.

Any ideas about where this timeout come from?

```
19:20:27,640 ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container
for bundle pentaho-i18n-webservice-bundle due to unresolved dependencies [(objec
tClass=org.pentaho.osgi.i18n.LocalizationService)]
**java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(Blu
eprintContainerImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.r
un(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19:20:27,673 ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container
for bundle pdi-dataservice-server-plugin due to unresolved dependencies [(object
Class=org.pentaho.caching.api.PentahoCacheManager)]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(Blu
eprintContainerImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.r
un(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

thank you!

Comment: it is not able to make connection (Unable to start blueprint container) this mighe be related with firewall issue.